# Oracle "Equal" faster than "not equal"

Tags: performance, oracle

I have a simple question:

somebody told me that the query:

```
select a1, a2, sum(b1)
from myTable
where a1 ='bla' and a2='blabla' and a3 ='aaa'
```

is faster then

```
select a1, a2, sum(b1)
from myTable
where a1 ='bla' and a2='blabla' and a3!='bbb'
```

I can understand that in some case in general a = is faster than a !=. but in this case I have a SUM(b1). for this i have to read all myTable.

Thank You.
Regards

Comment: Did that "somebody" provide benchmark or something?

Comment: Why do you 'have to read all myTable'? Your `where` clause is filtering, so you're not summing all values for `b1`, and unless you only have two values in `a3` the result will be different. (Whether you get a full table scan is a separate question).

Comment: Actually its depends on you query logic and database structure,In your example , Equal is faster because equal operator directly match the string and not equal taking time retrieve non-equal string.

Comment: sum(b1) doesn't mean in any way that you have to read all myTable.

Comment: Your queries look like they are missing a `group by` clause.

Comment: Yep there is a group by too :( sorry.

Answer (score 3):

The somebody is pretty much right.

Even when two queries are going to project exactly the same rows from a table, a query that uses a predicate on a column having only two values, "1" occurring once and "2" making up the remainder is more likely to use an index with:

```
column = '1'
```

than it is with:

```
column != '2'
```

Even when there is a histogram to identify the skew you'd be better off with an equals.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/070db/3